# Tips for manually writing SQL Server upgrade scripts

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, data-migration

We have some large schema changes coming down the pipe and are in needs of some tips in writing upgrade scripts manually. We're using SQL Server 2000 and do *not* have access to automated tools nor are they an option at this point in time. The only database tool we have is SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Do you also not have access to Visual Studio?

Comment: We do have VS2008, however it doesn't support SQL Server 2000 for database projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the database to a local machine with has a newer version of SQL, then you can use the 'Generate Scripts' feature to script out a lot of the database objects.

Make sure to set in the Advanced Settings to script for SQL Server 2000.

If you are having problems with the script generated, you can try breaking it up into chunks and run it in small batches. That way if you have any specific generated scripts you can just write the SQL manually to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

While not quite what you had in mind, you can use Schema comparing tools like [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), and then just script the changes to a sql file, which you can then edit by hand before running it. I guess that would be as close to writing it manually without writing it manually.

If you -need- to write it all manually i would suggest getting some intellisense-type of tools to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Your upgrade strategy is probably going to be somewhat customized for your deployment scenario, but here are a few points that might help.

- You're going to want to test early and often (not that you wouldn't do this anyway), so be sure to have a testing DB in your initial schema, with a backup so you can revert back to "start" and test your upgrade any number of times.
- Backups & restores can be time-consuming, so it might be helpful to have a DB with no data rows (schema-only) to test your upgrade script.  Remember to get a "start" backup so you can go back there on-demand.
- Consider stringing a series of scripts together - you can use one per build, or feature, or whatever.  This way, once you've got part of the script working, you can leave it alone.
- Big data migration can get tricky.  If you're doing data transformations, copying or moving rows to new tables, etc., be sure to check row counts before the move and account for all rows afterwards.
- Plan for failure.  If something goes wrong, have a plan to fix it -- whether that's rolling everything back to a backup taken at the beginning of the deployment, or whatever.  Just be sure you've got a plan and you understand where your go / no-go points are.

Good luck!